# Python (Tkinter)- Selecting specific Pandas dataframe from Tkinter combobox

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter, filter

I am having trouble with a Tkinter app I am making where the user would first select the dataframe from a combobox (combobox #1) which is a list of facilities within a given year (i.e., 2021 or 2022).  After the dataframe is identified, the user would select a list of facilities by state in a second combobox.

If I preselect the dataframe, everything works fine.  However, the user may want different years and does not want to use the Tkinter Filedialogue function. Basically, they want a dropdown menu that selects the dataframe. As I have it now, I can get it to work if I use the Input option from the command prompt, but I don't want to do that (see TEMP_SOLUTION section).

**Bottom line** - how can I first select the dataframe from a combobox (i.e., combobox #1) and make the state combobox use this selected dataframe as its source?  Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk

# function to get unique values
def unique(list1):
    x = np.array(list1)
    print(np.unique(x))

def make_df(): #I'd like to make the dataframe from here, but I am having trouble
    val = n3.get()
    if val == 'df2022':
        df = df2022
    else:
        df = df2021

def on_click():
    val = n.get()
    df2 = df[ df['state'] == val ]
    print(df2)
       

#DATAFRAMES       

df2022 = pd.DataFrame({
   'id': ['1','2','3'],
   'state': ['mi','mi','oh'],
   'provname': ['abc facility','123 facility','acme facility'],
   'workdate':['1/1/2022', '1/3/2022', '6/8/2022']
})

df2021 = pd.DataFrame({
   'id': ['4','5','6'],
   'state': ['al','al','az'],
   'provname': ['jimmy state facility','mack 10 facility','heathcliff facility'],
   'workdate':['3/3/2021', '12/13/2021', '10/31/2021']
})

#TEMP SOLUTION - I don't want to do this with the command prompt, but it's all I can get to work right now
temp_idea = input('enter df2021 or df2022: ')
if temp_idea == 'df2021':
    df = df2021
else:
    df = df2022

# Create Combobox for selecting dataframe (NOT WORKING)
n3 = tk.StringVar() 
da = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 60, textvariable = n3) 
  
da['values'] = ['df2022', 'df2021']
da.grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 20)

ttk.Button(window, text = "Add Dataframe", command=make_df).grid(column = 2, 
          row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 10)

#STATE FILTER

values = ['all'] + list(df['state'].unique())

window = tk.Tk() 
window.title('Combobox') 
window.geometry('600x400')
window.focus_set()
  
ttk.Label(window, text = "Main Menu",  
          foreground ="black",  
          font = ("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(row = 0, column = 1) 

#FILTER STATE - PART 1
ttk.Label(window, text = "Select the State:", 
          font = ("Times New Roman", 12)).grid(column = 0, 
          row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 29)

n = tk.StringVar() 
state = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 60, textvariable = n) 
state['values'] = sorted(list(df['state'].unique()))
state.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 20)

ttk.Button(window, text = "OK", command=on_click).grid(column = 2, 
          row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 10)

state.current()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update combobox `state` based on selected dataframe inside `make_df()`.  Also you can bind on `<<ComboboxSelected>>` virtual event instead of using the <kbd>Add Dataframe</kbd> button:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

def make_df(event=None):
    global df
    val = n3.get()
    if val == 'df2022':
        df = df2022
    else:
        df = df2021
    # update combobox 'state'
    values = ['all'] + sorted(df['state'].unique())
    state['values'] = values
    state.set('all') # select 'all' initially


def on_click():
    val = n.get()
    df2 = df if val == 'all' else df[ df['state'] == val ]
    print(df2)


#DATAFRAMES

df2022 = pd.DataFrame({
   'id': ['1','2','3'],
   'state': ['mi','mi','oh'],
   'provname': ['abc facility','123 facility','acme facility'],
   'workdate':['1/1/2022', '1/3/2022', '6/8/2022']
})

df2021 = pd.DataFrame({
   'id': ['4','5','6'],
   'state': ['al','al','az'],
   'provname': ['jimmy state facility','mack 10 facility','heathcliff facility'],
   'workdate':['3/3/2021', '12/13/2021', '10/31/2021']
})


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Combobox')
window.geometry('600x400')
window.focus_set()

ttk.Label(window, text = "Select Dataframe:",
          font = ("Times New Roman", 12)).grid(column = 0,
          row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 29)

# Create Combobox for selecting dataframe (NOT WORKING)
n3 = tk.StringVar()
da = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 60, textvariable = n3)
da['values'] = ['df2022', 'df2021']
da.grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 20)

da.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', make_df)  # use virtual event instead of button

#STATE FILTER

ttk.Label(window, text = "Main Menu",
          foreground ="black",
          font = ("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#FILTER STATE - PART 1
ttk.Label(window, text = "Select the State:",
          font = ("Times New Roman", 12)).grid(column = 0,
          row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 29)

n = tk.StringVar()
state = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 60, textvariable = n)
state.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 20)

ttk.Button(window, text = "OK", command=on_click).grid(column = 2,
          row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 10)

window.mainloop()
```

Note that you should create `Tk()` before creating other tkinter stuff.

Comment: This really helped on many levels, thank you!